# How to Make Top Value of DropDownList Item Bold C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, webforms

I have this drop down list, and I need to make the top value bold. How do I do this?

```
ddlDefaultSkins = new DropDownList();
ddlDefaultSkins.ID = "ddlDefaultSkins";
ddlDefaultSkins.ToolTip = "Select Default Clock Skin";
ddlDefaultSkins.SelectedValue = "CustomClock";
ddlDefaultSkins.AutoPostBack = true;

ddlDefaultSkins.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
ddlDefaultSkins.Items.Add("CustomClock");
ddlDefaultSkins.Items.Add("swissRail");
ddlDefaultSkins.Items.Add("chunkySwiss");
ddlDefaultSkins.Items.Add("fancy");
ddlDefaultSkins.Items.Add("machine");
ddlDefaultSkins.Items.Add("classic");
```

Comment: SharePoint Properties  This is part of a ToolBox Class.

Comment: How can you get -1 on a question.  Some elitest coder thinks it is not good enough I guess.

Comment: I wonder the same thing myself sometimes.  Try SuperPrograman's answer, I would think that would work.

Comment: It looks like it, I will have to try next week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could use:

```
var item = new ListItem("CustomClock");
item.Attributes.Add("style", "font-weight: bold");

ddlDefaultSkins.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: It seems like a good solution I am going to try it.  Might be next week for me to try it I have another project to work on.  +1 for it thanks and if it works I'll come back and give you the correct answer check.  thanks :)

Comment: I have found that the DropDown list only works for background-color and that is it.  Your solution to apply the style works great and is standared.  I should have known that :) Ill give you the answer because it does work if I just switch it to background-color thanks!

Answer (score -2):

```
foreach (ListItem item in DropDownList1.Items)
{
    //if you want to apply for some selected items check the condition on item.Text or item.Value based on your requirement.
    if (item.Text == "Some Value")
    {
        //Change font weight 
        item.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("font-weight", "bold");
        //Change font color
        item.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("color", "red");
    }
}
```